# Why does BigDecimal divide cause rounding when it should fit within the significant digits?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Why does BigDecimal divide cause rounding to happen even though the value should fit comfortably in 4 significant digits?

```
BigDecimal realPercent = new BigDecimal(1.25, new MathContext(4));
// 1.25
BigDecimal percentDivider = new BigDecimal(100, new MathContext(4));
realPercent = realPercent.divide(percentDivider, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
// 0.01
```

It's possible to make divide behave like I want by setting the precision on the method call, but it doesn't explain why it doesn't already do it.

```
realPercent.divide(percentDivider, 4, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
// 0.0125
```

Comment: Might want to indicate which language this is; there are multiple languages with BigDecimal types.

Comment: @MSalters aight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide-java.math.BigDecimal-java.math.RoundingMode-) of `divide(BigDecimal, RoundingMode)`:

> Returns a `BigDecimal` whose value is `(this / divisor)`, and whose scale is `this.scale()`

The last part is important - the scale of your initial value is 2 (the unscaled value is 125). Because you've called an overload that pins the scale, the closest result available is scale=2, unscaled=1, i.e. 0.01.

Comment: Ah. I was under the impression that the `MathContext` would set the scale (not true!). You're right, if I `realPercent.setScale(4)` after creating the first `BigDecimal` then doing `realPercent.divide(percentDivider, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)` it will divide on the scale I was expecting. Cool.

Answer (score 1):

By explicitly setting the rounding mode in your divide call here:

```
realPercent = realPercent.divide(percentDivider, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

you override the used `MathContext`. If you specify the `MathContext` with rounding mode right away, it works as expected:

```
BigDecimal realPercent = new BigDecimal(1.25, new MathContext(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
// 1.25
BigDecimal percentDivider = new BigDecimal(100, new MathContext(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
realPercent = realPercent.divide(percentDivider);
//0.0125
```